# Show that the set of integers endind in 0 or 5 has the same cardinality as the set of integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The title is the question I am asked, word for word.

How would I show this?

They are both infinite, therefor have the same cardinality?

I'm also a bit confused on the wording of "the same cardinality as the set of integers". What exactly is being asked? Thanks for any help.

Is this enough to show proof?

0,   5,   10,   15 . . .  5n

0,   1,   -1,   2, . . . n

Comment: You want to show there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of all integers and the set of integers ending in 0 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the definitions you've used, but it should boil down to this.

Two sets have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection (a function that's invertible; one-to-one and onto) between them. This definition applies to finite and infinite sets alike.

So, they're both "infinite" in size, but that's not precise enough to guarantee they have the same cardinality. You need to find a bijection between the integers, and the set of integers ending in $0$ or $5$.

Hint ('theorem' with a similar proof):

There are exactly as many even integers as there are integers.

Comment: thanks, i edited my question.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I think you've got the idea of it, but you've only listed the *nonnegative* multiples of $5$. If you use the negatives as well (as you should, judging by the way the question is phrased), the bijection is much simpler: $n \mapsto 5n$ will work.